# Hiding my rails div using JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

My products view:

```
<a href="#" id="show_metrics">Show Metrics</a>
  <div id="metrics" class="hidden">
<%="Number of Primary Products: #{Product.total_product_size(rating_set).count}"%><br/>
<%="Number of Recommendations: #{Product.total_recommendation_size(rating_set).count}"%><br/>
<%="Percentage of Bad Recommendations: #{bad}/#{total} = #{number_to_percentage(percentage_bad, :precision => 2)}"%>
</div>
```

products.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $("a#show_metrics").click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $("div#metrics").toggle()
```

The "Show Metrics" link shows on my view, however nothing happens when the link is clicked, however when I view my page source I see my metrics div as a hidden value. What do I need to change to show the metrics info when the "Show Metrics" link is clicked.

Generated HTML:

```
<div id="metrics" class="hidden">
Number of Primary Products: 5
<br>
Number of Recommendations: 105
<br>
Percentage of Bad Recommendations: 0/0 = NaN%
</div>
```

Generated JS:

```
(function() {
$(function() {
return $("a#show_metrics").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
return $("div#metrics").show();
});
});
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
$("div#metrics").removeClass("hidden")
```

so add it to your code like this:

```
$ ->
  $("a#show_metrics").click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $("div#metrics").removeClass("hidden")
```

conversely, if you want to hide it you'll do:

```
$("div#metrics").addClass("hidden")
```

Comment: Still not working. When I click the show metrics link, the bottom text moves down to make space for the metrics div, however no text is displayed.

Comment: have you inspected the generated javascript? also, any other javascript being used on the page? especially involving this `hidden` div?

Comment: Updated my question with generated js and html

Comment: updated solution. use `.removeClass('hidden')` instead of `.show()`

Comment: one last question, how can I toggle between adding and removing the hidden class on div#metrics?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery ->
  $("a#show_metrics").click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $("div#metrics").toggle()
```